# Apply Alloy UI 1.5 datepicker to multiple instances

Tags: jquery, alloy-ui

I want to create Alloy UI datapickers on multiple form fields:

```
<div id="date_1_wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_1" />
</div>
<div id="date_2_wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="datepick" id="date_2" />
</div>
```

Using JQuery I can do it using following code:

```
$('.datepick').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
```

But how to achieve same functionality in Alloy UI?

For now I use following code, but this code apply DatePickers by ID, not by CSS class in loop:

```
AUI().use(
        'aui-datepicker',
        function(A) {

            new A.DatePicker (
                    {
                        calendar: {
                            dateFormat: '%d/%m/%Y'
                        },
                        trigger: '#date_1'
                    }
            ).render('#date_1_wrapper');

            new A.DatePicker(
                    {
                        calendar: {
                            dateFormat: '%d/%m/%
                        },
                        trigger: '#date_2'
                    }
            ).render('#date_2_wrapper');
        }
);
```

I think this code can be used in beginning, but what is next? How to deal with input's and div's ID's?

```
(A.all('.datepcik').each(function() {)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same thing as jQuery. `render()` is expecting either a `Node` or a `selector`. Try this:

**--UPDATED--**

```
A.all('.datepick').each(function(node, index, nodeList){
    new A.DatePicker({
        calendar: {
            dateFormat: '%d/%m/%'
        },
        trigger: node
    }).render();
});
```

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/NodeList.html#method_each

Comment: this don't work.. Please note that I need to specify (in DatePicker costructor) not only input id, but also wrapper Id. This is the problem.

Comment: @MyTitle, I've updated the code, see if that works. I used trigger rather than render. I'm getting this from: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/dynamic_data_mapping/custom_fields.jspf#L108-L120